# Android Chrome behaving badly with background property

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

I'm developing a personal website, and I'm having some issues with Chrome on Android.
I have a background image covering up all the page, and it works fine in every browser I own (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox) *and* on every mobile browser I own (Chrome on iOS, Safari on iOS, even default Android browser).

Here's the CSS for my `body`:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What happens on Chrome for Android is that the background covers only the available viewport (above the fold), while disappearing below the fold.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Above the fold the background disappears]
Could it be a problem with using `body` instead of the more classic wrapper `#container` `div`? I would really like to resolve this without having to clutter my markup; I'm confident it's something possible since it works in really most browsers.

Maybe it's a Chrome for Android bug?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but it's probably because you explicitly set the height and width on body, try removing those lines.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the problem was explicitly setting `height: 100%` on the `body`, which made it stick to the viewport height.

By removing that constraint, now the background extends to all the content.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to min-height: 100% for body and html should give you the same affect.

Otherwise could you provide an example URL or code example of jsbin.com

Comment: Nope, I'm sorry. It wasn't that, but the above comment resolved the issue. Thank you anyway!